# What is the hash used in PyPI package URL?

Tags: python, pypi

Example URL:

```
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/65/d5d8303c7dd6a46964cc360e6d95137821493bbd7e4644165afdac13149e/numpy-1.22.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl#sha256=94dd11d9f13ea1be17bac39c1942f527cbf7065f94953cf62dfe805653da2f8f
```

Multiline version for readability:

```
https://files.pythonhosted.org/
packages/fb/65/d5d8303c7dd6a46964cc360e6d95137821493bbd7e4644165afdac13149e/
numpy-1.22.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl#
sha256=94dd11d9f13ea1be17bac39c1942f527cbf7065f94953cf62dfe805653da2f8f
```

Here are 2 hashes in this URL

```
fb/65/d5d8303c7dd6a46964cc360e6d95137821493bbd7e4644165afdac13149e
sha256=94dd11d9f13ea1be17bac39c1942f527cbf7065f94953cf62dfe805653da2f8f
```

The second (`94dd11`) is obviously the SHA256 checksum of the package file (`numpy-1.22.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`).

What is the first hash value (`fb65d5`)? It seems to be a SHA256 checksum, but how is it computed?

Answer (score 2):

The path hasher is defined as ["blake2_256"](https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/blob/9738ebb2/warehouse/forklift/legacy.py#L77) at https://github.com/pypi/warehouse and the file content is used as hashed data.

So in the above example

```
export url='https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/65/d5d8303c7dd6a46964cc360e6d95137821493bbd7e4644165afdac13149e/numpy-1.22.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl#sha256=94dd11d9f13ea1be17bac39c1942f527cbf7065f94953cf62dfe805653da2f8f'
curl -s $url --output - | python3 -c "import sys, hashlib; print(hashlib.blake2b(sys.stdin.buffer.read(), digest_size=32).hexdigest())"
fb65d5d8303c7dd6a46964cc360e6d95137821493bbd7e4644165afdac13149e
```

Comment: What is the `65` in the URL?

Comment: the third and the fourth hex digit of the digest string